# Create a function which returns on event listener being triggered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

In JavaScript, I have an event listener and I have a separate function that needs to return a value only when the listener is triggered.

Example of what I am looking for:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });



function test(){ 
//check if myBtn has been pressed then return 1;
//otherwise keep waiting and don't return anything until myBtn is clicked.
}
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep waiting"? The JavaScript engine should just stop executing anything if that function is called?

Comment: Why don't you just put the test function inside of the event listener `function()` with a `return` statement?

Comment: Maybe I oversimplified the problem, inside the function I have another event listener from chrome webrequest (onBeforeRequest), when this listener is triggered, I want to wait for the result of a two button notification before I proceed with my decision on what to do with that web request.

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer By keep waiting I mean that I do not want the function to return if the event listener of myBtn is not triggered, I am writing a code that pauses some web requests and displays a notification for each of the paused requests, once the users clicks the button of that notification, then the webrequest resumes. But I am still not able to figure how to do this given that I have multiple requests and multiple notifications pending at the same time.

Comment: Can you please reframe your question. ? Are you looking to implement a function on a notification / callback ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var is_button_pressed = 0;

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    is_button_pressed = 1;
});



 function test(){ 
    return is_button_pressed===1?1:undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use test() inside your original event listener and then for the event listener inside test(), use a closure to check the value of myBtn, and then return the value you want.

Honestly, I don't understand the point of 2 event listeners inside each other. For a RESTful request, why would you want to pause the request. You could just as simply capture the parameters of the request with the 1st button, and use the 2nd button to actually send the request. This is a lot easier to code and reason about.